# How do I use Reduce to multiply several matrices in reverse order?

Tags: r

Say I have a list of matrices, `W`, and I want to perform both `W[[1]] %*% W[[2]] %*% W[[3]] %*% W[[4]] %*% ...` and `W[[4]] %*% W[[3]] %*% W[[2]] %*% W[[1]] %*% ...`.  It seems like `` Reduce(`%*%`, W) `` and `` Reduce(`%*%`, W, right = T) `` should do it, but that doesn't seem to work.  The code below gives an example:

```
set.seed(90088)
W <- list(
    matrix(sample(1:5, size = 25, replace = T), ncol = 5),
    matrix(sample(1:5, size = 25, replace = T), ncol = 5),
    matrix(sample(1:5, size = 25, replace = T), ncol = 5),
    matrix(sample(1:5, size = 25, replace = T), ncol = 5)
    )
Reduce(`%*%`, W)
Reduce(`%*%`, W, right = T)
W[[1]] %*% W[[2]] %*% W[[3]] %*% W[[4]]
W[[4]] %*% W[[3]] %*% W[[2]] %*% W[[1]]
```

Does anyone know what `Reduce` (and particularly the `right = T` option) is doing?

Comment: `Reduce(`%*%`, rev(W))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reverse the order in which the elements are multiplied, just reverse the order of the elements in the list you feed in to `Reduce()`!

```
Reduce(`%*%`, rev(W))
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5]
# [1,] 11583  8978  9082 5034 10443
# [2,] 12759  9950  9967 5604 11565
# [3,]  7269  5686  5702 3176  6575
# [4,] 15459 12094 12050 6857 14060
# [5,]  9834  7684  7691 4314  8916
```

To see what `right=TRUE` does (and it is sort of interesting), examine the intermediate results of a simpler call to `Reduce()`:

```
Reduce(`*`, 5:1, accumulate=TRUE, right=FALSE)
# [1]   5  20  60 120 120
Reduce(`*`, 5:1, accumulate=TRUE, right=TRUE)
# [1] 120  24   6   2   1

## And a non-commutative function shows even more clearly how right=TRUE works:
Reduce(paste0, letters[1:5], right=TRUE, accumulate=TRUE)
# [1] "abcde" "bcde"  "cde"   "de"    "e"
```

Comment: Huh.  That's not what I expected `right = T` to do, but that is kind of interesting.  Thanks!

Comment: Following up on this, it looks like the `right` option determines which side `init` will be added to.  For example, ``Y <- sample(1:5, size = 5, replace = T) ; Reduce(`%*%`, W, init = Y, right = F)`` is equivalent to `Y %*% W[[1]] %*% W[[2]] ...` while ``Reduce(`%*%`, W, init = Y, right = T)`` is equivalent to `W[[1]] %*% W[[2]] %*% W[[3]] %*% W[[4]] %*% Y`.

Comment: @JakeFisher -- Good point. I just added another example using a non-commutative function that better illustrates why (also non-commutative) matrix multiplication was failing.